# Excel VBA InputBox not returning range values in loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have used this code in the past, but today it is not working for some reason. I have scoured the internet for answers, and from what I have read my InputBox is set up correctly. When i use the hard coded range my messageBox returns the correct cell values, but when I use the inputbox no values are returned.

I am fairly new to coding in VBA, and this seems like it should be an easy fix. Hopefully someone can help :)

```
Dim rRng As Range
Dim rCell As Range

Set rRng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select Cells to check", Type:=8)
'Set rRng = Sheets("Table 3-1").Range("F11:F13")
For Each rCell In rRng.cells
    a = rCell.Value
    MsgBox "Cell Value is: " & a
Next
```

Comment: I tried running this macro on another computer, and it worked just fine. Any one have an idea of what is happening on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have select cells containing values.  Your code works just fine.
Make sure you are on the proper sheet when you run the macro.

Comment: The cells do contain values, and I would like to use this macro in any workbook. When reading the MS help about InputBoxes the Application.InputBox is supposed to work with the 'Active' worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if the value in `rRng` variable is set properly by using `If
  rRng Is Nothing Then`
- Make sure there is no unwanted reference in the
  workbook.
- `VBA IDE > Standard tool bar > Goto Debug > Compile VBA code` may highlight the possible issue.

.

```
  Sub test()

    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rRng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select Cells to check", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Range selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        a = rCell.Value
        MsgBox "Cell Value is: " & a
    Next

End Sub
```